# After masking, copy command selects the complete canvas. How do I just select the masked object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have used a layer mask to select the Jar from the image.
When I select and copy the Jar to another document the whole transparent canvas is getting copied. Also when I select using transform tool, the whole canvas is getting selected.
How to just select the Jar?

Answer (score 1):

Do a <kbd>Ctrl / Command</kbd>+click on the layer mask thumbnail in the layers panel. That will load the mask as a selection.  Now when you copy and paste, it will only copy only the jar.

Comment: I am able to copy the object in the same document but it doesn't get copied to another document the same way.

Comment: @Mady It makes no difference if I paste the copy to the same or another Photoshop document. The result is the same. I just checked it.  What is different about it when you try?

Comment: @Mady see [example here](https://imgur.com/FQ6m9ek)

Answer (score 0):

To copy the layer with mask, just drag the jar (on canvas with move tool, not in layer panel, and with no active selection) and drop it in the other document. 
It will copy the layer with the mask into your other document.

If you want to copy with selection (but you will loose the interresting property of a mask) apply the mask to your layer (right clic on layer panel) and then you can select and copy/paste.

(sorry for my mistakes in english, it's not my native language)